# Safari positioning messing with transition

Tags: iframe, safari, transition, conflict, vimeo

Having difficulty with transitioning a div height in safari. Looks great in FF, Chrome and IE. It can transition initially ok (it is buggy) but it then will transition the opposite way to shrink back.

The div starts at height: 0 and transitions to height: 115px on hover. It transitions back to 0 but instead of the top growing up from the bottom. The top stays at the expanded position and the bottom shrinks up to meet it.

One more thing, it is an unordered list and the transition is on each li. The error only seems to happen on the last hovered over li.

Here's the test site. The li's in question are the six post teaser boxes:

> http://iwanttolisten.in/pctest

Was using css transitions but now switched to jquery to see if that would fix the issue. I'm wondering if it has something to do with the position attribute on a parent element. Here's the code. There is some wordpress php snippets copied over in it.

```
<ul id="post_teasers">

            <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                <li>
                    <div class="looped_post">
                        <div class="thumbnail_loop">
                            <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                        </div>
                        <div class="loop_content">
                            <div class="loop_title">
                                <div class="title_pad"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php if ( function_exists('the_title_attribute')) the_title_attribute(); else the_title(); ?>"><?php limit_title($post->post_title, 24); ?></a></div>
                                <div class="teaser_meta">
                                    <?php the_author(); ?>,&nbsp;<?php bp_profile_field_data( array('user_id'=>get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ),'field'=>'Neighborhood' )); ?>
                                </div>
                            </div>  
                            <div class="post_expand">
                                <div class="loop_excerpt">
                                    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                                </div>
                            </div>  
                        </div>  
                    </div>
                </li>

                <?php do_action( 'bp_after_blog_post' ); ?>

            <?php endwhile; ?>

            </ul>



   .looped_post {
float: left;
height: 305px;
margin: 0 12px 25px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    width: 255px;

    }

.looped_post:after {
    -moz-border-bottom-colors: none;
    -moz-border-left-colors: none;
    -moz-border-right-colors: none;
    -moz-border-top-colors: none;
    border-color: transparent #F2F1DF;

    -webkit-border-image: none;
    -moz-border-image: none;
    border-image: none;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 20px 20px 0 0;
    bottom: 0;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    width: 0;
    z-index: 3;
}


.thumbnail_loop {
    width: 255px;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.post_expand {
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;

    /*
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out 0s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-out 0s;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-out 0s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease-out 0s;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-out 0s;
    */


}

/*
ul#post_teasers li:hover .post_expand {
    height: 115px;
}
*/

.loop_content {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border-top: 4px solid #8A7B67;
    bottom: 0;
    font-family: noto serif,serif;
    position: absolute;
    width: 255px;
    z-index: 2;
}

.loop_title {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
    height: 110px;
    position: relative;
    width: 255px;
}

.loop_title a {
    color: #3E2711;
    font-family: noto serif,serif;
    font-size: 27px;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 30px;
}

.title_pad {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 20px;
}

.teaser_meta {
    bottom: 15px;
    color: #856A4F;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-style: italic;
    padding: 0 0 0 20px;
    position: absolute;
}

.loop_excerpt {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
    color: #3E2711;
    font-size: 14px;
    height: 60px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0 20px 20px;
    width: 215px;
}

.loop_excerpt p:first-child:first-letter {
    float: left;
    color: #9FA615;
    font-size: 45px;
    line-height: 20px;
    padding-top: 4px;
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
    font-family: Georgia;
}

        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('ul#post_teasers li').hover(function(){
                $(".post_expand", this).stop().animate({height:'115px'},{queue:false,duration:500});
            }, function() {
                $(".post_expand", this).stop().animate({height:'0px'},{queue:false,duration:500});
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved! It was a conflict with an embedded Vimeo video part way down the page.

The logged-in page has the same code but without all the other landing page elements below it and I noticed the issue didn't persist once logged in. There are a lot of elements on the landing page but I just used the inspector to display: none all of them until I figured out where the conflict was.

It's also worth nothing there was a slight issue with the nav menu transitions with Safari and that was fixed by this as well.

Will be replacing the video with a linked image of it. Sweet!